# Kolab setup - access denied

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions

I am trying to setup kolab collaboration software on my Ubuntu 14.04 server.  I am following the instructions [here](https://docs.kolab.org/installation-guide/ubuntu.html).

The errors I get is during 'setup-kolab':

```
Could not import LDIF file '/tmp/ldifsAgNzA.ldif'.  Error: 65280.  Output: ./ldif2db: 85: [: 0: unexpected operator
importing data ...
[04/Jul/2015:19:28:52 -0500] - mkdir_p /var/lib/dirsrv/slapd-core: error -5966 (Access Denied.)
[04/Jul/2015:19:28:52 -0500] - Can't start because the database directory "/var/lib/dirsrv/slapd-core/db" either doesn't exist, or is not accessible
[04/Jul/2015:19:28:52 -0500] - ERROR: Failed to init database (error -1: BDB0092 Unknown error: -1)

Error: Could not create directory server instance 'core'.
Exiting . . .
Log file is '/tmp/setupOrcgdf.log'
```

I have created a new user and group (called kolab-srv and kolab-srv-grp) and then run setup-kolab.  I get the error above.  It doesn't seem to matter if I am logged in as root, run this with a sudo command or add the kolab-srv user to the admin group on the box...I get the same message each time.

Each time I would get the message I would delete the directory `/var/lib/dirsrv/slapd-core`, make a change, and start over with the setup only to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install 389-ds on Ubuntu 14.04, which seems to be part of kolab. I ran into this same issue. It appears to be a "bug" in the ldif2db script that gets called along the way. The version of that script that gets installed via the normal packages has:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Which fails on line 85:

```
if [ $? == 1 ]
```

Which isn't valid for /bin/sh. I was able to get past this by changing the /usr/sbin/ldif2db script to start with:

```
 #!/bin/bash
```

Very hacky and is bound to cause issues elsewhere, but...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on Debian Testing (strech) while trying to get Dogtag running.

I've created symlink from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` but still got the same error.

Then I checked the user and group assigned to `/var/lib/dirsrv`

```
# ls -lha /var/lib/dirsrv/<br> 
total 8.0K<br> 
drwxr-x---  2 dirsrv dirsrv 4.0K Mar  9  2015 .<br> 
drwxr-xr-x 29 root   root   4.0K Apr  8 17:00 ..<br>
```

So to work around that I used `dirsrv` as user and group for the installation and then it worked.